# How to set up a shortcut to a directory in Mac OS X Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

What I'd like to be able to do is when I'm in Terminal is to type:

```
cd myFolderShortcut
```

And for it to go straight to a directory I have a set up with this alias. Is this possible?

I did do a google for it and Aliases may be what I want, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: If what you want is a shorter command for cd'ing into a specific directory, all you need to do is add the following to your `~/.bashrc`: `alias myalias='cd /path/to/directory'`. You can replace `myalias` with any custom command name you wish.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/wiki, it might also work for you.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You don't need a shortcut file or anything like that.

---

You can set up an alias in `~/.bash_profile` by adding the following line, so you just need to type `myFolderShortcut` to go there (without `cd`):

```
alias myFolderShortcut='cd /Users/danielbeck/Documents'
```

You also need to type the above command or

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to get this to take effect. 
This works from any directory, but requires that your login shell be `bash` (which is OS X's default)

---

You can, of course, create symbolic links to other directories in your home directory. Then, when you open Terminal and are in your home directory, `cd`ing takes you to the linked directory.

```
ln -s /Users/danielbeck/Documents/Projects myProjectsDir
```

Then, type `cd myProjectsDir` and you're there (the displayed path contains `myProjectsDir` though, not `Documents/Projects`).

The symbolic link will show in Finder. To hide it, type `chflags -h hidden myProjectsDir`.

This will work only when you're in your home directory to start with (`cd` without arguments takes you there quickly; you can type both commands on the same line: `cd && cd myProjectsDir`).

Comment: `cd` as `cd ~` is my favorite alias.

Comment: @Rob It's not technically an alias. `cd` without argument just implies `~`. I like `cd -` better, by the way.

Comment: Hi, I could not get your technique to work. I wanted to created a shortcut to my solr directory. It currently lives in my: alias solr='cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/WhoAt/solr/whoat/' Perhaps my path isn't correct?

Comment: @Leon Are you using the `bash` shell?

Comment: I think I'm using default I think...

Comment: My solution is as above, but I put the symbolic link in the root `sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/htdocs www` so that wherever I am I can go cd /www/...

Comment: On El Capitan I get "No such file or directory" when typing in `source  ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @jimmykup The paragraph above that command basically says you need to create the file first (or, well, to edit it, which implies creating if it doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks. The issue was that my folder had a space in it. Wrapping apostrophes around `shortcut='cd /Users/..'` threw me off and I forgot to add `"`

Comment: It should be noted that once I close terminal I lose the shortcut functionality and have to redo it. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: @jimmykup No, as `.bash_profile` is loaded in every newly opened `bash` shell (unless you're using iTerm, which IIRC makes `bash` load `.bashrc` instead). Did you follow the instructions in my answer?

Comment: @DanielBeck I did. I may just not understand Terminal well enough. Maybe there's something I'm suppose to do before your instructions? I open terminal, setup the alias, and then it's already working. `source ~/.bash_profile` always returns the error I mentioned above. And then closing Terminal and re-opening removes the alias. This is the extent of the steps I take.

Comment: @jimmykup My guess is the file you're editing has a different name, like `bash_profile` or `.bash_profile.txt`. `ls` to check and `mv` to fix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47838/discussion-between-jimmykup-and-daniel-beck).

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks. The wording/format is super confusing. e.g. when reading: "You can set up an alias in ~/.bash_profile by adding the following line, so you just need to type myFolderShortcut to go there (without cd):" You say add the following line but then switch your words to something else without a mention of the following line. I made an edit but it was rejected. Can you take a look into my [suggestion](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/852328) and revise accordingly yourself?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but this might help someone.

After you follow @Daniel Beck's answer above, and add the alias to the bash_profile like he mentioned, you have to type the following in the terminal window:

```
source .bash_profile
```

This will make all your aliases work.

I've got this from this answer on stack overflow. It has worked for me. I hope it works for someone looking for this...

[How Do I create a terminal shortcut to this path?](https://superuser.com/questions/606308/how-do-i-create-a-terminal-shortcut-to-this-path/606312#606312)

Comment: Thanks, this came in handy. Also `source ~/.bash_profile` might be a more general way of writing it

Answer (score 2):

Just one thing I wanted to add, because it happened to me and took me quit some time to find the error. 
I wrote
    `alias myFolderShortcut = 'cd /Users/danielbeck/Documents'`
because I like to have spaces between my equal signs. But it gave me an error.

So after removing the spaces it worked.

So use

```
alias myFolderShortcut='cd /Users/danielbeck/Documents'
```

I hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Helped me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the CDPATH environment variable. 
This works for the `cd` command the way PATH works for running programs
— if you type a `cd` command with a parameter that doesn’t
begin with `/` (or `~`),
the shell looks for a directory by that name under each component of CDPATH. 
For example, if you want quick access to the following directories:

- `/Users/benhowdle89/Documents/Projects/Project42`
- `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/WhoAt/solr/whoat`
- `/the/quick/brown/fox/jumps/over/the/lazy/dog`

then set CDPATH to the following value

```
:/Users/benhowdle89/Documents/Projects:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/WhoAt/solr:/the/quick/brown/fox/jumps/over/the/lazy
```

and you’ll be able to use the commands `cd Project42`, `cd whoat`,
and `cd dog`, etc.  The value *begins* with a colon (`:`)
so as to include an initial null entry.  In some shells,
this is necessary to get `cd` to look in the current directory first.

This should work in most POSIX-type shells; e.g., `bash` and `ksh`. 
For `bash`, put a command like

```
export CDPATH=:/Users/benhowdle89/Documents/Projects:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/…
```

into your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`. 
(If you use `~/.bashrc`, you may be able to leave out the `export`.) 
For csh-type shells, use `cdpath` and the appropriate csh-style syntax.