# How do I create a terminal shortcut to this path?

Tags: macos, terminal, shortcuts, .bash-profile

So I'm having a problem creating a shortcut to a deep folder. None of the examples I've seen on Superuser have helped :(

This is my path: `cd / Applications / MAMP / htdocs / whoat / solr / whoat`

I would like to create the shortcut `solr` to reach that directory

I have to use `cd /` to get into my computer from the desktop, because I can't navigate into my Applications folder otherwise.

---

**UPDATE**

I was able to get into my .bash_profile via VIM

```
sudo vi ~/.bash_profile
```

This is what I currently have inside of it, I added the last 3 lines, however none of the shortcuts work:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/share/python"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib"
alias sublime="/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
alias edit="/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
alias solr="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/WhoAt/solr/whoat/"
```

When I type `solr` enter, or `sublime` enter, nothing happens

Comment: Could the downvote explain himself?

Comment: You question shows zero research. A quick google could have told you what the `~/.bash_profile` is, let alone the other questions to asked. On that note, you asked multiple unrelated questions in the same Question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is defined an alias `solr` which will cd to the named directory-:

```
alias solr='cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whoat/solr/whoat'
```

Note the use of single quotes - double quotes will cause the `cd` to go to to the home directory.

I sometimes prefer to add a pwd to the alias as a check and reminder of what the current working directory is-:

```
alias solr='cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whoat/solr/whoat;pwd'
```

Ideally you would put this alias in your `.bash_profile` in your home directory. You can use a text editor such as `TextEdit` or `vim` to add the alias command to `.bash_profile`. Then to load the new alias into your shell type-:

```
source .bash_profile
```

Comment: I put that into my bash_profile, and when I run just solr nothing happens. I don't get an error message however, just nothing happens. When I do LS I see my main Mac directory

Comment: Don't forget to source the revised .bash_profile - see edited answer. Also the spacing in the path - I've removed that now in my answer.

Comment: if you are still having problems try setting the alias direct to the shell. Add the pwd as a check (see above).

Comment: Still nothing working :( I added the 2nd path with no spaces + the ;pwd and then ran into this: Leons-MacBook-Pro:/ leongaban$ source .bash_profile
-bash: .bash_profile: No such file or directory

Comment: ok. First enter in command line this-: `alias solr='cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whoat/solr/whoat;pwd'`. Then if no error type `solr`. That should put you in the correct directory. If that works, then type `cd` to get to home dir. Then type `source .bash_history`. Does that help?

Comment: Whoa that did work! I guess I'll just save alias solr='cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whoat/solr/whoat;pwd' into a Note file :)

Comment: Excellent. Also, I believe the problem with the aliases in .bash_profile are the double quotes. Try changing those to single quotes - the shell gets confused with the spacing after the `cd` otherwise.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9201/discussion-between-leon-and-suspectus)

Answer (score 5):

#### Links

To create links, you use the `ln` command. See `man ln`.
You could do it like `ln -s /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whoat/solr/whoat /where/you/want/link`, where:

- The first path is what you are linking
- The second path is where the link will be

#### Directory Navigation

`man cd`

There are two ways to navigate with `cd`, absolute and relative.
The easiest way to get from home to applications is `cd /Applications/`

- Capitalization matters....

#### Editing Files

Doing `~/.bash_profile` isn't how you edit a file.... you were trying to run the file like it was a script (even though it a config file)
Also, here is a decent [article](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) on the difference between `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`

If you want to edit it from terminal, you have to use an editor, like vim/emacs/pico etc.

- `vim ~/.bash_profile`
- `emacs ~/.bash_profile`
- `pico ~/.bash_profile`

#### Editing on Mac

As you are on OS X, you could use `open -e ~/.bash_profile` to open with TextEditor

- Don't use sudo!

#### Sudo

You shouldn't be using `sudo` to try to 'force edit' you user's files.

- It can mess up a file's permissions to be root's
- It can lead to damaging accidents when you don't know what you are doing (so ***you*** should avoid it)
- Just because you were doing it wrong, doesn't make `sudo` a magic wand to fix commands.

#### In Conclusion

Please read a few unix tutorials...

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed answer, I still could not get the shortcut to work, even after editing my .bash_profile... the command just won't work unless I just directly type in 'alias solr='cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/whoat/solr/whoat;pwd' then the shortcut. I can just save that in a note file. I will now proceed to watch some Unix tutorials +1