# Alias to shortcut from home folder not working

Tags: macos, bash

As per this question on [How to set up a shortcut to a directory in Mac OS X Terminal?](https://superuser.com/q/375092/180163)

I've added the following alias:

```
alias MeteorApps=‘cd ~/Documents/Github/MeteorApps’
```

By adding it to the bash profile with

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

However, when I try to type in `MeteorApps`, I get the following error:

```
-bash: ‘cd: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a syntax problem. Replace both `‘` by `'`.

Comment: That's what I get for opening in the default text editor which converted for me.  Instead, I opened in with `pico`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've no access to Mac OS X.