# Set up a shortcut to a folder with spaces and hyphens

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, alias

Hi: I am a Mac OS X user and my work offers us Microsoft OneDrive.

The problem is the path name for folders stored on the OneDrive has spaces and hyphens. Like this:

`~/OneDrive - My University Name`

So, I would like to set up shortcuts to various subfolders of my OneDrive, i.e. projects, courses:

`~/OneDrive - My University Name/Courses`

`~/OneDrive - My University Name/Projects`

I have read through [this](https://superuser.com/questions/375092/how-to-set-up-a-shortcut-to-a-directory-in-mac-os-x-terminal) and have been able to set up an alias that looks like this:

`alias courses='cd "~/OneDrive - My University Name"'`

But it's not working, because where I am falling down is how to get the quotes right. Reading the question linked above, it appears that the alias needs to be fully quoted, but so does the path name to the university in order for the change directory to work.

I think this is a question about quoting and escaping characters, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tilde is only expanded when unquoted. You could use:

```
alias courses='cd ~/"OneDrive - My University Name"'

alias courses='cd ~/OneDrive\ -\ My\ University\ Name'
```

The variable `$HOME` always has the same value but *is* expanded inside double-quotes:

```
alias courses='cd "$HOME/OneDrive - My University Name"'
```

(In all three examples, the outer `'...'` quoting can (and should) remain, because the whole alias contents will be interpreted a second time whenever that alias is run.)